# Looking for a react switch toggle (ios style or any other) component with changable size

Tags: reactjs

All 5 or 6 which I've just check don't have a size property. I didn't want to fiddle with them and I'm sure about a year ago I saw one.

Thanks

Comment: By size, do you mean width of the switch box? If yes, react-flexible-switch can help you out - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flexible-switch

Comment: I meant mostly altogether the diameter and width etc.. I can see this one allows to change them. Thanks a lot, I will give it a try.  You could maybe copy your comment as an answer to tick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By size, do you mean width of the switch box? If yes, [react-flexible-switch](http://npmjs.com/package/react-flexible-switch) can help you out